# I would really like to make my Py project a stand alone exe and if you have any suggestions on how to improve i am wide open thank you

Tags: python, exe

1. so this is my code and i would really like to make it a stand alone executable and i am using python 3.8.3 .
2. if you have any suggestions of improvment or have managed to find a way to do this i would be very happy.
3. i have already tried the command-cd C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Desktop\K.A.T ai offline then entered that then put in the command- pyinstaller --onefile K.A.T_AI_offline.py
4. but it does not end up working and it does give me a file in the dist folder.
5. so please could you help me make a stand alone executable so i can show my computer science teacher and my friends without them having to download python and the other modules.

```
    # All the modules being imported
    import sys
    import time
    from tkinter import Tk, messagebox, simpledialog
    import PySimpleGUI as sg
    import pyttsx3

    # The voice settings
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
    engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id) #changing index changes voices but ony 0 and 1 are working here

    # This creates a dictionary
    the_master = {}
    the_world = {}
    the_word= {}

    # Defining how to read the info in capital_data.txt
    def read_from_file():
        with open('capital_data.txt') as file:
            for line in file:
                line = line.rstrip('\n')
                country, city = line.split('/')
                the_world[country] = city

    # Defining how to write new info in new_data.txt            
    def write_to_file(country_name, city_name):
        with open('new_data.txt', 'a') as file:
            file.write('\n' + country_name + '/' + city_name)

    def read_from_master_file():
        with open('master_data.txt') as file:
            for line in file:
                line = line.rstrip('\n')
                MName, MName = line.split('/')
                the_master[MName]= MName
                
    def write_to_master_file(master_name):
        with open('master_data.txt', 'a') as file:
            file.write('\n' + master_name + '/' + master_name)

    def read_from_alphabet_file():
        with open('phonetic_alphabet.txt') as file:
            for line in file:
                line = line.rstrip('\n')
                letter, word = line.split('/')
                the_word[letter] = word

    # Popup box to ask wether K.A.T know this user 
    sg.theme('DarkBlack')
    layout =[[sg.Text('Are You One Of My Masters')],
            [sg.ReadFormButton('Yes'),sg.ReadFormButton('No')]]
    form = sg.FlexForm('Do I Know You')
    form.Layout(layout)
    engine.say('are you already one of my masters')
    engine.runAndWait()

    button, values = form.Read()
    if button is button == 'No':
        form.close()
        print ('Well In That Case')
        print ('Hello user'), engine.say('well, in that case, Hello user'), engine.runAndWait(), print ('I am KAT'), engine.say('I am KAT'), engine.runAndWait(), print ('Which stands for Know.Alot.of.Things'), engine.say('Which stands for,    Know a lot of things'), engine.runAndWait()

    # see's if K.A.T know the Master
    if button is button == 'Yes':
        form.close()
        engine.say('oh, so which master are you?')
        engine.runAndWait()
        root = Tk()
        root.withdraw()
        read_from_master_file()
        query_master = simpledialog.askstring('Name Of Master', 'Which Master Are You?')
        query_master = query_master.capitalize()
        if query_master in the_master:
            master_result = the_master[query_master]
            engine.say('My apologies master,' + master_result)
            engine.runAndWait()
            choice_of_country = ('Would you like to know the Capital city of a Country')
            choice_of_phonetic_alphabet = ('Would you like to know how to spell a word or letter in the Phonetic Alphabet')    
            yes_master = print (choice_of_country), engine.say('Would you like to know the Capital city of a Country.'), engine.runAndWait(), print ('OR'), engine.say('or.'), engine.runAndWait,  print (choice_of_phonetic_alphabet), engine.say('Would you like to know how to spell a word or letter in the Phonetic Alphabet'), engine.runAndWait(), engine.say('Which one would you like to know, just type 1 or 2'), engine.runAndWait(),
            choice = input('Which one would you like to know, just type 1 or 2') 
        else:
            engine.say('sorry you are not one of my masters')
            engine.runAndWait()

    if button is button == 'No':
        form.close()
        engine.say('oh, and, please may you enter the name, that you wish to be called.')
        engine.runAndWait()
        root = Tk()
        root.withdraw()
        new_master = simpledialog.askstring('New Master',
                                            'Oh And Please May You Enter the name that you wish to be called')
        new_master = new_master.capitalize()
        if new_master == 'Oliver' :
            print('OH well in that case you can just')
            engine.say('OH well in that case you can just')
            print('GET LOST')
            engine.say('GET LOST')
            engine.runAndWait()
            sys.exit(0)
        elif new_master in the_master:
                print('You Are A Master Silly.')
                engine.say('you are already a master, silly, you, are master,  ' + new_master)
                engine.runAndWait()
                write_to_master_file == False
        elif new_master != 'Oliver':
            write_to_master_file(new_master)
            root.destroy()
            engine.say('hello,'+new_master)
            engine.runAndWait()
            choice_of_country = ('Would you like to know the Capital city of a Country')
            choice_of_phonetic_alphabet = ('Would you like to know how to spell a word or letter in the Phonetic Alphabet')    
            no_master = print (choice_of_country), engine.say('Would you like to know the Capital city of a Country.'), engine.runAndWait(), print ('OR'), engine.say('or.'), engine.runAndWait,  print (choice_of_phonetic_alphabet), engine.say('Would you like to know how to spell a word or letter in the Phonetic Alphabet'), engine.runAndWait(), engine.say('Which one would you like to know, just type 1 or 2'), engine.runAndWait(),
            choice = input('Which one would you like to know, just type 1 or 2')

        if simpledialog in (None, 'Ok'):
            root.destroy()

        new_master = new_master.capitalize()
        new_master = simpledialog.askstring('New Master',
                                            'Oh And Please May You Enter the name that you wish to be called')
        the_master[new_master] = new_master

    if choice == '1' :
        capital_cities = ('Well just type in the Country into the little window that will pop up and i\'ll tell you the Capital City')
        print (capital_cities)
        engine.say('Well just type in the Country into the little window that will pop up and i\'ll tell you the Capital City')
        engine.runAndWait()
        # Creates the Tkinter window 
        root = Tk()
        root.withdraw()
        read_from_file()
        engine.say('Now, type the name of the country you would like to know the capital city of.')
        engine.runAndWait()
        while True:
            query_country = simpledialog.askstring('Country', 'Type the name of a country:')
            query_country = query_country.capitalize()

            if query_country in the_world:
                result = the_world[query_country]
                messagebox.showinfo('Answer',
                                    'The capital city of ' + query_country + ' is ' + result + '!')
                engine.say('The capital city of ' + query_country + ' is ' + result)
                engine.runAndWait()
            else:
                new_city = simpledialog.askstring('Teach me',
                                                'I don\'t know! ' +
                                                'What is the capital city of ' + query_country + '?')
                engine.say('i don\'t know!'+
                        'what the capital city of'+query_country+'is'+
                        'but if you know you can type it in the box')
                engine.runAndWait()
                the_world[query_country] = new_city
                write_to_file(query_country, new_city)
                break

    elif choice == '2' :
        phonetic_alphabet = ('Well just type in the Word or Letter into the little window that will pop up and i\'ll tell you how to write it out, but in using the phonetic alphabet')
        print (phonetic_alphabet)
        read_from_alphabet_file()
        engine.say('Well just type in the Word or Letter into the little window that will pop up and i\'ll tell you how to write it out, but in using the phonetic alphabet')
        engine.runAndWait()
        root = Tk()
        root.withdraw()
        while True:
            query_word = simpledialog.askstring('Word', 'Type a word or letter :')

            if query_word in the_word:
                word_result = the_word[query_word]
                messagebox.showinfo('Answer',
                                    'The way you would say' + query_word + ' in the phonetic alphabet is ' +word_result + '!')
                engine.say('the way you would say'+query_country+'in the phonetic alphabet is'+result)
                engine.runAndWait()
                break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason why it didnt work for you is because your **exe have dependencies**, so you need to **take it out of the dist folder and execute it from the main folder of your project** so that it can access the dependencies

Here is a link that should tell you everything you need to know about it : [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/)

Comment: You welcome, if it worked for you, could you please accept my answer as the solution ? thank you